# Highlighting text to speech in c# windows form

Tags: c#

How do I highlight text while speaking in c# windows form? 
tried this :

```
public void HighlightWordInRichTextBox(System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox,string word, SolidColorBrush color)
{
    //clear all formatings
    //System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox  rt= (System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.ichTextBox;
   TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.SelectionStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, null);
    //Current word at the pointer
    TextRange tr = FindWordFromPosition(textPointer,word);
    if (!object.Equals(tr, null))
    {
        //set the pointer to the end of "word"
        textPointer = tr.End;
        //apply highlight color
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, color);
     }
}
public TextRange FindWordFromPosition(TextPointer position, string word)
{
    while (position != null)
    {
        if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            string textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            // Find the starting index of any substring that matches "word".
            int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(word);
            if (indexInRun >= 0)
            {
                TextPointer start = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
                TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Length);
                return new TextRange(start, end);
            }
        }
        position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }
    // position will be null if "word" is not found.
    return null;
}
void reader_SpeakProgress(object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
{
    //show the synthesizer's current progress 
    label2.Text= e.Text;
    SolidColorBrush highlightColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    HighlightWordInRichTextBox(richTextBox1, e.Text, highlightColor);
}
```

but errors in this code 
got error at document :

> 'system.windows.forms.richtextbox' does not contain a definition for 'document' and no extension method 'document' accepting a first argument of type 'system.windows.forms.richtextbox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

Comment: please append the errors that you are receiving to the end of the question.

Comment: Try fixing the errors.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell us what errors you are having so that we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Your error makes it very clear.  `TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.SelectionStart, **richTextBox.Document**.ContentEnd)` The property `Document` doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

You've used WPF code for a WinForms control. WPF's [RichTextBox *does* have a `Document` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx), but [WinForms's doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx).

You're probably looking for something like:

```
new TextRange(richTextBox.SelectionStart, richTextBox.SelectionLength);
```